# How to display month name by number?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a number represented month and i want to replace it with month name, date filter not working:

```
{{ monthnumber|date:"M" }}
```

I want to place two links - next month and previous month, but i have only number of month.

How to do it?

Comment: For others coming to this question, check whether this is required consider what you are trying to achieve with [Django Date based Class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/) in mind

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll need a custom template filter to convert the number into a month name. Pretty simple if you use the `calendar` module from the standard library:

```
import calendar

@register.filter
def month_name(month_number):
    return calendar.month_name[month_number]
```

Usage example:
`{{ 5|month_name }}`
will output `May`

Comment: user1242163's answer does not require a custom filter.

Comment: user1242163's answer does require a datetime object, not an integer

Answer (score 19):

you should use :

```
{{ datetimeobj|date:"F" }}
```

read [this](http://blog.tkbe.org/archive/date-filter-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: (Link is dead as of today)

Answer (score 10):

Well, it's not :

```
{{ monthnumber|date:"M" }}
```

You should try this :

```
{{ datetimeobj|date:"M" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you do not want to format a date object passed into a Django template (like the other answers clearly show), but rather you'd prefer to simply get the current date's month number;
here is the built-in tag you can use to do that:

```
{% now "n" %}
```

From the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#now

Here are the built in date tags you can use with `{% now [""] %}`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Answer (score 0):

The version of the custom filter with `calendar` didn't work for me (it takes string as a argument), so I created a different version of the filter with `datetime.datetime.strptime`, that takes int as a argument:

```
import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def int_to_month_name(month_number):
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_number, "%m")
    full_month_name = datetime_object.strftime("%B")
    return full_month_name
```

Usage: `{{ month_number|int_to_month_name}}`