# How to change annotated month int in a dictionary into a month name?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django framework, I have used annotation to sum up all the Amounts paid in a specific month in a year.
This is working fine but the problem is that am unable to convert the month int into a month name in the template

**views.py**

```
def income_report(request):
    context = {}
    if grab_data_passed == 'monthly':
       daily_data=Income.objects.values('date__year', 'date__month')\
       .annotate(amount=Sum('amount'))
       context['daily_data']=daily_data
       return render(request, 'reports/incomes_report_details.html', context)
```

**template**

```
  {% for fo in daily_data %}
         <tr>
           <td>{{ fo.month }}</td>
            <td>{{ fo.amount }}</td>
         </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can change this annotated month into a month name in the templates.
I know I have to first convert date__month back to month name in views before I pass it to the templates but how?

Comment: Can you please add your `Income` model ?

Comment: check this answer, it is having better answer than the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385976

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display month name by number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385751/how-to-display-month-name-by-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own template filters like this in your case :

From django official documentation :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        extra_filters.py
    views.py
```

extra_filters.py :

```
from django import template
import calendar

register = template.Library()


...


@register.filter
def month_to_string(month):
    return calendar.month_name[month]
```

and then in your template, first import extra_filters.py :

```
{% load extra_filters %}
...
...



{{ fo.month|month_to_string }}
```

Comment: am getting this error Invalid filter: 'month_to_string'

Comment: @MK Patel, the above answer gave me a solution to my problem, now am good to go to another module

Comment: @MUGOYADIHFAHSIH He just edited my answer so it's more readable and more optimized, just look at month_to_string function.

Comment: Yes, exactly I optimized the code only nothing else.